# Which relationship type would be between a professor and a course?

Tags: sql, erd

Q:  What is the relationship type in between Courses and Professors table in a college?

I assumed it can go like many-to-many as a course can have many professors and a professor can teach different many courses.

Or on the other hand, one-to-many where professor could teach multiple course and a course can be taught only by one?

Which relationship is the correct one for this case?

Comment: In my opinion, many-to-many is the correct one.

Comment: Why do you assume there is a single correct answer unless there's more information *you have access to* that you've not included in your question?